# is it idiomatic to say "to coax the baby not to cry"?

Tags: word-request

Your baby is crying

is it idiomatic to say "**to coax the baby not to cry**" or any better / common way to say it?

> **[coax](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coax?q=%20coax)**: to persuade somebody to do something by talking to them in a kind and gentle way
>
> synonym cajole
>
> coax somebody/something (into doing something) She coaxed the horse
>   into coming a little closer.
>
> coax somebody/something (into/out of something) He was coaxed out of
>   retirement to help the failing company.
>
> coax somebody/something (+ adv./prep.) She had to coax the car along.
>
> Police managed to coax the man down from the ledge.
>
> coax (somebody/something) + speech ‘Nearly there,’ she coaxed.

Comment: No, you can't coax somebody to *not* do something. You can coax them to *stop*, as in the examples.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this video says "5 seconds to coax the baby not to cry" (https://www.dianjinwa.com/video/14607.html)

Comment: The video appears to be on a Chinese website, so probably not written by a native speaker.

Comment: Tom -That's not even from an *English* source!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I stand corrected](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231302/is-it-idiomatic-to-say-to-coax-the-baby-not-to-cry?noredirect=1#comment439755_231302). Apparently, [*some* Americans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiet%20the%20baby%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%2Ccoax%20the%20baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquiet%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoax%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0) do indeed ***coax*** babies...

[image]

...but [***Brits don't***...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiet%20the%20baby%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%2Ccoax%20the%20baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquiet%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

The reason ***coaxing*** doesn't work for me (as a Brit, obviously) with crying babies is that it strongly implies getting a *cautious, reluctant* party to do something they're not really *willing* to do. So you might quite reasonably [*coax the baby to **eat***,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22coax%20the%20baby%20to%20eat%22) but that implication doesn't sit well when what you want it to do is ***stop crying***.

Maybe that implication - of [*coaxing the **frightened***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28coax%20the%20frightened%29%2B%28coaxed%20the%20frightened%29%2B%28coaxing%20the%20frightened%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28coax%20the%20frightened%29%20%2B%20%28coaxed%20the%20frightened%29%20%2B%20%28coaxing%20the%20frightened%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(coax%20the%20frightened)%20%2B%20(coaxed%20the%20frightened)%20%2B%20(coaxing%20the%20frightened)%3B%2Cc0) [child, animal, whatever] - is either weaker or non-existent for Americans, I dunno. But I would avoid it in the exact cited context.

Comment: what about 
"calm the crying baby down", is it more common than "soothe the crying baby"

Comment: You could have followed my "some Americans" link as easily as I've just done...

Comment: ...and [*added **calm the baby** to the search strings yourself*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiet+the+baby%2Csoothe+the+baby%2Ccoax+the+baby%2Ccalm+the+baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquiet%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoax%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalm%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cquiet%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoothe%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoax%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalm%20the%20baby%3B%2Cc0) It occurs, yes.

Comment: ...and I don't have a problem with ***calming** crying babies*, just a slight distaste for ***coaxing** them not to cry*.

Comment: Here's [one more NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=quiet+a+crying+baby%2Csoothe+a+crying+baby%2Ccoax+a+crying+baby%2Ccalm+a+crying+baby&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cquiet%20a%20crying%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoothe%20a%20crying%20baby%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalm%20a%20crying%20baby%3B%2Cc0) that might help. It shows that ***quiet, soothe, calm** a crying baby* all occur reasonably often, but ***coax a crying baby*** doesn't occur often enough to show on the chart.